# Is it possible to use format() function with a string in format's place?

Tags: python

I'm using a format() in python and I want to use a variable `pokablelio` so that the person could choose how many numbers to output after the dot. When I try to put the variable alone after the comma it outputs: `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`. I tried replacing some characters or making the whole string in a parentheses but that didn't work.

Right now I'm wondering: Can I even use a variable as a string to put it in format's place?

(note: The machine should have a "'.10f'" string in the variable)

[Error and the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVUOn.png)

Comment: Please, no screenshots of code. Copy your code and paste into your question (click the edit button). Highlight what you pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve your code's line-feeds and whitespace. This way we can copy/paste to tinker/troubleshoot, as none of us want to transcribe a screenshot.

Comment: The `format` function doesn't know whether it is a string variable or a string literal.  Your PROBLEM is that you are trying to embed single quotes.  You don't need those.  Just `"."+pokablelio+"f"`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use variables as part of the format specifier, just include them inside additional curly braces:

```py
>>> n_places = 10
>>> f'{1.23:.{n_places}f}'
'1.2300000000'
```